# I am making a function to print the lyrics of 99 bottles song. When I use the console.log, it works but it doesn't work when I use return

Tags: javascript, return, console.log

```
function beer() {

  var n = 99;

  while (n>1) {
    
    var m = n-1;

    console.log((n +  "bottles of beer on the wall," + n + "bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around," + m +  "bottles of beer on the wall."));

    n--;

  }

  console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.");

}
```

Comment: What do you mean return. Show an example or explain what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function beer() {
  var n = 99;
  var lyrics = "";
  while (n > 1) {
    var m = n - 1;
    lyrics +=
      n +
      "bottles of beer on the wall," +
      n +
      "bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around," +
      m +
      "bottles of beer on the wall.";
    lyrics += "\n\n";
    n--;
  }
  
  lyrics+=(
    "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n"
  );

  return lyrics;
}

const response = beer();
console.log(response);
```

You just need to append all the lyrics to the string and at the end just return from the function.

I hope this will answer the question